# Como sumar o restar diferentes valores en una lista en python

Tags: python

tengo una duda de como podria resolver un inconveniente en python. Tengo la siguiente lista

```
balance = [ {Codigo: 1, debe: Decimal('10.0'), haber: Decimal('-25.0')}, {Codigo: 2, debe: Decimal('0.0'), haber: Decimal('-35.0')},{Codigo: 1, debe: Decimal('20.0'), haber: Decimal('-35.0')}]
```

Quisiera saber la manera en la que podria sumar los valores correspondientes a debe y haber cuando el codigo sea el mismo, tal que el resultado sea:

```
[ {Codigo: 1, debe: Decimal('30.0'), haber: Decimal('-60.0')}, {Codigo: 2, debe: Decimal('0.0'), haber: Decimal('-35.0')}
```

he intentado crear un diccionario auxiliar

```
temp = {}
```

y luego realizar la operacion

```
for d in balance:     
 temp[d["codigo"]] = temp.get(d["codigo"], 0) + d["debe"]
```

para finalmente reasignar los valores a la lista original

```
balance = [{"codigo":c, "debe":d} for c,d in temp.items()]
```

Lo que me pregunto es como podria agregar tanto los valores de debe como haber a la operacion puesto a que de esta manera se esta agregando solo 1

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Siéntete libre de ir a [edit] e incluir en tu pregunta el código python con el que tienes problemas para resolver este enunciado que nos compartes. Tienes la duda, bien, pero... qué intentaste para resolver tu problema?

Comment: Hola, por el momento he intentado crear un diccionario auxiliar `temp = {}` y luego realizar la operacion `for d in balance:
    temp[d["codigo"]] = temp.get(d["codigo"], 0) + d["debe"]`, para finalmente reasignar los valores a la lista original `balance = [{"codigo":c, "debe":d} for c,d in temp.items()]`  pero no puedo hacerlo tanto con debe como con haber al mismo tiempo

Comment: De nuevo: Por favor. Edita. La. Pregunta. Como ves, acá en los comentarios el código no tiene indentado y se pierden características que pueden tener relación con tu problema...

Comment: Lo siento, ya edite la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [List comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) para sumar todos los los valores que sean de un código específico:

```
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal

balance = [ {'Codigo': 1, 'debe': Decimal('10.0'), 'haber': Decimal('-25.0')},
           {'Codigo': 2, 'debe': Decimal('0.0'), 'haber': Decimal('-35.0')},
           {'Codigo': 1, 'debe': Decimal('20.0'), 'haber': Decimal('-35.0')}]

balance

[{'Codigo': 1, 'debe': Decimal('10.0'), 'haber': Decimal('-25.0')},
 {'Codigo': 2, 'debe': Decimal('0.0'), 'haber': Decimal('-35.0')},
 {'Codigo': 1, 'debe': Decimal('20.0'), 'haber': Decimal('-35.0')}]

este_codigo=1

#Debe
print(sum([codigo['debe'] for codigo in balance if codigo['Codigo']==este_codigo]))

#Haber
print(sum([codigo['haber'] for codigo in balance if codigo['Codigo']==este_codigo]))

30.0
-60.0
```

Con esto en mente, ya puedes hacer más cosas. Por ejemplo, puedes crearte una lista de totales donde almacenes el valor total de debe y de haber de cada código:

```
cods_unicos = list(set([codigo['Codigo'] for codigo in balance])) # lista códigos únicos

nuevo_balance=[]

for num_codigo in cods_unicos:
    total_debe= sum([codigo['debe'] for codigo in balance if codigo['Codigo']==num_codigo])
    total_haber= sum([codigo['haber'] for codigo in balance if codigo['Codigo']==num_codigo])
    nuevo_balance.append({'Codigo':num_codigo, 'debe':total_debe, 'haber':total_haber})

nuevo_balance

[{'Codigo': 1, 'debe': Decimal('30.0'), 'haber': Decimal('-60.0')},
 {'Codigo': 2, 'debe': Decimal('0.0'), 'haber': Decimal('-35.0')}]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!, me ha funcionado perfecto... podria al igual sumar y restar los valores agregandole una condicional más aparte del codigo?

Comment: @KEVINALEXANDERVELASCORAMOS Depende de la condición pero seguramente sí. Si tienes dudas, puedes abrir otra pregunta y seguro que alguien te ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Yo pensaba en crear un diccionario en el que ir añadiendo cada diccionario ya sumado, intentando recorrer la lista el menor número de veces posible.

```
balance = [
    {'Codigo': 1, 'debe': '1.0', 'haber': '-2.0'},
    {'Codigo': 2, 'debe': '0.1', 'haber': '-1.0'},
    {'Codigo': 2, 'debe': '0.1', 'haber': '-1.0'},
    {'Codigo': 2, 'debe': '0.1', 'haber': '-1.0'},
    {'Codigo': 1, 'debe': '1.0', 'haber': '-2.0'}
]

aux = {}
for dato in balance:
    x = dato['Codigo']
    if x not in aux:
        aux[x] = dato
    else:
        debe, haber = float(aux[x]['debe']), float(aux[x]['haber'])
        aux[x]['debe'], aux[x]['haber'] = f"{float(dato['debe']) + debe:.1f}", f"{float(dato['haber']) + haber :.1f}"
mi_balance = list(aux.values())

print(mi_balance)
```